# Screw size for Dell PowerConnect rack ears?

Tags: hardware, switch, mount, rack

Does anyone know what the Screw size is (Thread and length) that Dell use on their PowerConnect Switches, to connect the ears to the switch?

In particular the 6224 and 8224?

Answer (score -1):

It's been about a year since I've used PowerConnects, but I'm pretty sure that the rack ears just have two holes each for the screws.  What size and length you need depends on the type of rack; more specifically, whether you're using captive nuts or pre-threaded rails.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, what screws attach the ears to the powerconnects themselves, not the PCs to the rack.

Comment: Ah!  Sorry, all I can remember is that they're short and countersunk... sorry.